# Flatten Pandas DataFrame from nested json list

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

perhaps somebody could help me. I tried to flat the following ist into a pandas dataframe:

```
[{u'_id': u'2',
  u'_index': u'list',
  u'_score': 1.4142135,
  u'_source': {u'name': u'name3'},
  u'_type': u'doc'},
 {u'_id': u'5',
  u'_index': u'list',
  u'_score': 1.4142135,
  u'_source': {u'dat': u'2016-12-12', u'name': u'name2'},
  u'_type': u'doc'},
 {u'_id': u'1',
  u'_index': u'list',
  u'_score': 1.4142135,
  u'_source': {u'name': u'name1'},
  u'_type': u'doc'}]
```

The result should look like:

```
|_id   | _index | _score | name | dat        | _type |
------------------------------------------------------
|1     |list    |1.4142..| name1| nan        | doc   |
|2     |list    |1.4142..| name3| nan        | doc   |
|3     |list    |1.4142..| name1| 2016-12-12 | doc   |
```

But all I tried to do is not possible to get the desired result. 
I used something like this:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame.from_dict, res['hits']['hits']), axis=1)['_source'].T
```

But then I loose the types wich is outside the _source field. 
I also tried to work with

```
test = pd.DataFrame(list)
for index, row in test.iterrows():
  test.loc[index,'d'] =
```

But I have no idea how to come to the point to use the field _source and append it to the original data frame.

Did somebody has an idea how to to that and become the desired outcome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  

df = json_normalize(data)
print (df)
  _id _index    _score _source.dat _source.name _type
0   2   list  1.414214         NaN        name3   doc
1   5   list  1.414214  2016-12-12        name2   doc
2   1   list  1.414214         NaN        name1   doc
```