# Python: Efficient way to replace single quotes in a dataframe to doublequotes

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe operation as follows:

```
master['c']=master['c'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

This converts all the rows in column 'c' into a json representation but with single quotes. But inorder to Redshift to recognize this JSON object, I need to replace the single quotes into double quotes.

```
master['c']=master['c'].apply(lambda x:json.dumps(x))
```

But my data is very huge (around 3M records) and it is taking 40 minutes to convert the data into a proper JSON object. Is there any other way? I tried writing it to a file and replacing the characters but it didn't work the way it is supposed to. Thank you for reading

**EDIT 1**:

SAMPLE DATA:

`{"major":"rule1":{"id":12,"name":"bhargavi"},"rule2":{"id":32,"name":"qwerty"}‌​‌​}`

I first convert the dataframe into json output using `to_json()`. Then I replace all the backslashes using `replace()`.

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: Also is possible use `master['c']=master['c'].apply(json.loads)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Don't I need to use lambda here?. Would json.loads work fine?

Comment: `lambda` here is not necessary. Try in small data sample.

Comment: Okay I did. It gave me an error saying `the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'`

Comment: I think omit `master['c']=master['c'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: That throws an exception too.

Comment: How do you create dataframe? From `json`? Maybe need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38610160/2901002), [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

Comment: Um no. The JSON is actually a very complex nested json that im creating from dataframe.to_json() at diffrerent levels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144206/discussion-between-bhargavi-sri-and-jezrael).

Comment: "This converts all the rows in column 'c' into a json representation but with single quotes." No, it doesn't. That doesn't make any sense, and regardless, `ast.literal_eval` only outputs Python objects​ not a "json representation"